# Node js assert.equal multiple values

Tags: node.js, testing, assert

Is it possible to use assert.equal method in Node.js like this:

```
assert.equal(some_var, 12 OR 34);
```

If some_var is 12 or 34 I need the test to have passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
expect([12, 34]).to.include(some_var);
```

i usually use chai to do unit test, but the concept should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

## No dependencies

```
assert([12, 34].includes(some_var));
```

It actually ends up 2 characters less than the chai solution